# Access a ResourceContext instance from a static context

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

In Jersey JAX-RS:

Is there a way to access an instance of ResourceContext from a static context?  So far I have come-up empty-handed and have tried a number of approaches that fail to do what I expect.  Here's an example snippet of what I want to achieve:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.*;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

@Singleton
@Provider
public static class MyClass
{
    private static MyClass singleton;

    @Context
    private ResourceContext context;

    @PostConstruct
    private void constructor () 
    {
       MyClass.singleton = this;
    }

    public static <T> T acquireResource(Class<T> clazz)
    {
       return MyClass.singleton.context.getResource(clazz);
    }
}
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work properly as I suppose providers are lazy loaded.  I'm not even sure the "@Singleton" annotation does anything.

I've also tried extending the WebAppResourceConfig which is an instance of Application, but this broke my application and I don't fully understand why.

Comment: Don't do things without knowing why you're doing them.

Comment: Please explain why you need to `ResourceContext` in a `static` context.

Comment: The reason why is because I'm extending third-party library Swagger that automatically documents a JAX-RS based API.  Although Swagger is called from a JAX-RS resource, the code I must extend is deeply entrenched, was instantiated using "new" and does not support dependency injection, and I do not have a reference to any JAX-RS resource class objects in that context.  The code I am working on to extend that interface would obtain a reference to a certain MessageBodyWriter singleton and call methods on it.

Comment: The ultimate purpose is to dynamically generate example request entities for API calls using the MessageBodyWriter inverse of its MessageBodyReader for the request entity.